# JQuery UI Dialog off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a long page that I create a dialog with a fixed position on, how can I prevent it from going off screen from the bottom or from the top after I have scrolled down, it seems that it uses the boundries of the page instead of the boundries of the viewport.

SIDE QUESTION 1#: How can I disable the graying out effect in the back?

SIDE QUESTION 2#: Can I have multiple dialogs that don't overlap?

Comment: According to the jQuery-UI docs it should be in the viewport and shouldn't gray background ("modal") by default. Please show your code

Comment: Yes sorry, just noticed the modal: true in the options. It seems to work great except when the page is longer than the viewport.       `autoOpen: false,
      height: 140` are the only properties I use with the newest jquery-ui.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want gray background you should put

```
modal: false,
```

Comment: Sorry but this should be the right answer for this topic.